# The function IntrospectionClient in Identityserver4 always returns Unauthorized

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I want to use the function IntrospectionClient to verify the token in identity server, but it always returns: Unauthorized

Identity server startup code:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddSigningCredential(myPrivatecert)
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetResources())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
            .AddTestUsers(Config.GetTestUsers())
            .AddValidationKey(myPubliccert)
            .AddJwtBearerClientAuthentication()
            .AddValidators();
```

I add a api resource, a client info and a test user in config file

My Config is :

```
public class Config
{
    //ApiResource
    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetResources()
    {
        return new List<ApiResource>
        {
            new ApiResource("api")
        };
    }

    //Client
    public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
    {
        return new List<Client>
        {
            new Client()
            {
                ClientId = "site",
                AccessTokenLifetime = 180,
                RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Absolute,
                AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime = 1800,
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,
                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },
                AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                RequireConsent = false,
                AllowedScopes =
                {
                    "api"
                },
                AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,
                AllowOfflineAccess = true
            },
        };
    }

    //TestUser
    public static List<TestUser> GetTestUsers()
    {
        return new List<TestUser>{
            new TestUser{
                SubjectId="1",
                Username="wyt",
                Password="123456",
                Claims = new List<Claim>()
                {
                    new Claim("wawa", "aoao"),
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

My Client Startup is:

```
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                }).
                AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = "http://localhost:6001";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.ApiName = "api";
                });
```

get token :

```
        //token
        var tokenClient = new TokenClient(dico.TokenEndpoint, "site", "secret");
        var tokenResponse = tokenClient.RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync("wyt", "123456").Result;
```

want use introspection:

```
var introspectionClient = new IntrospectionClient(
            dico.IntrospectionEndpoint,
            "api",
            "secret");

        var vresponse = await introspectionClient.SendAsync
            (
                new IntrospectionRequest { Token = tokenResult.AccessToken }
            );
```

but the vresponse is always Unauthorized
where is wrong?

Comment: I am  having same issue , are  you able to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, the documentation is not very clear.
You need to add an ApiSecret to your ApiResource:

```
public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetResources()
{
    return new List<ApiResource>
    {
        new ApiResource("api") 
        {
            ApiSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) }
        }
    };
}
```

And then you call the introspection endpoint passing the api name and the api secret, like you did:

```
var introspectionClient = new IntrospectionClient(
        dico.IntrospectionEndpoint,
        "api",
        "secret");
```